# How to find the scroll coordinates in ui:scrollWrapper

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

```
<ui:scrollerWrapper class="scrollerSize" aura:id="scroller">
 <aura:iteration items="{!v.pricebookEntries}" var="pricebookEntry" indexVar="index">         
                                        <tr class="slds-hint-parent" >                                                                                                
                                            <td width="6%">                                       
                                                    product
                                            </td>

                                            <td role="gridcell">
                                             price
                                            </td>
</aura:iteration>
</ui:scrollerWrapper>
```

---

```
scrollTo:function(component, event, helper) {
   var scrollwrap= component.find('scroller');
    scrollwrap.scrollTo(destination, xcoord, ycoord);
},
```

iam displaying 10000 records i want to find the scroll height when user scrolls the list.for each scroll i will load 20 records. please help me how to find the scroll coordinates

Comment: Why not just use data table with infinite scrolling?

Comment: i have seen the documentation here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/ui:scrollerWrapper/documentation .but i cant find how to get the coordinates on each scroll. please help me

Comment: yes u said correct. In lightning Datatable infinite scrolling is acheivable . but ineed to use only normal html table. if you know infinite scroll in normal table in aura:iteration .pls share your answer

Comment: I can use lightning datatable but in edit products i need to make the checkbox to true for the selected products in the list. I am unable to set the checkbox to true for the selected products in lightning datatable. so that reason i am using normal html table